# Google drive api, wont upload async

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am using Google.Apis.Drive.v3 to manage some files. My problem is I can only upload files the sync way. 
This async upload just wont upload the file:

```
    var service = GetService(i_user_credential, i_application_name);

    var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
    fileMetadata.Name = i_file_name;
    fileMetadata.Parents = new List<string> { i_folder_id };

    FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
    CancellationToken ctsUpload = new CancellationToken(); 

    using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(i_file_path, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
    {
        request = service.Files.Create(
            fileMetadata, stream, i_file_type);
        request.Fields = "id";
        request.UploadAsync(ctsUpload);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```
await request.UploadAsync(ctsUpload);
```